# How To Make Components Initialize After JPA Creates Schemas?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

**Context**

> The server runs on spring-boot and utilizes spring-data. The database
>   being used is postgresql.

**Problem**

> Some of the components read from information_schema, pg_user,
>   pg_policies, and pg_catalog. **These components' PostConstruct are
>   currently running before jpa schema creation does.** This means that the
>   information that the components are trying to fetch hasn't been
>   created by jpa yet, so the components crash.

**Prior Research**

> No errors are being thrown by hibernate itself. Running the server
>   twice makes the problematic components run correctly. This implies
>   that these components are running before jpa.
>
> **My properties file includes spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update** . I
>   tried to find the code behind spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto to see how
>   I could get the components to require it by way of @DependsOn, but I
>   have yet to find anything on it.
>
> I can't simply wait for ApplicationReadyEvent with an event listener
>   as that will break the dependencies between these components.

**Code**

These are my hikari data sources

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "server")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource server() {
        return (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "client")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "client.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource client() {
        return (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

I have a custom DataSource component.

```
@Component
public class DatabaseRouterBean {
    private final AwsCognitoConfiguration cognitoConfiguration;
    private final DatabaseService databaseService;
    private final HikariDataSource server;
    private final HikariDataSource client;
    private final ModelSourceInformation modelSourceInformation;

    public DatabaseRouterBean(
        @Qualifier("server") final HikariDataSource server,
        @Qualifier("client") final HikariDataSource client,
        final AwsCognitoConfiguration cognitoConfiguration,
        final DatabaseService databaseService,
        final ModelSourceInformation modelSourceInformation
    ) {
        this.server = server;
        this.client = client;
        this.cognitoConfiguration = cognitoConfiguration;
        this.databaseService = databaseService;
        this.modelSourceInformation = modelSourceInformation;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DatabaseRouter dataSource() {
        return new DatabaseRouter(cognitoConfiguration, databaseService, server, client, modelSourceInformation);
    }
}
```

The following is the implementation of the data source.

```
// could have a better name
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class DatabaseRouter implements DataSource {
    private final AwsCognitoConfiguration config;
    private final DatabaseService databaseService;
    private final HikariDataSource superuser;
    private final HikariDataSource user;
    private final ModelSourceInformation modelSourceInformation;
```

The custom data source component is used to create connections for entity managers using one of two accounts on the database for the purpose of multi-tenancy. One account is superuser while the other is a limited user account. Multi-tenancy is achieved through the use of policies. The custom data source runs SET_CONFIG on the connection.

DatabaseService is a very low level service class that supports reading from information_schema, pg_user, pg_policies, and pg_catalog.

```
@Service
@Log4j
public class DatabaseServiceImpl implements DatabaseService {
    private final HikariDataSource server;
    private final HikariDataSource client;
```

ModelSourceInformation has no dependencies. It is used to convert a class type into a configuration variable name and vice versa. It is used by the custom data source to populate SET_CONFIG based on the type of user. It supports defining configuration variables and tying them to models by way of annotations.

AwsCognitoConfiguration is simply a Configuration class that reads the cognito settings from the properties file.

**Defined Execution Order By Dependency**

1. DatabaseConfiguration, ModelSourceInformation, AwsCognitoConfiguration
2. DatabaseService
3. DatabaseRouter
4. JPA
5. Rest of beans

**The following components are initialized before jpa. They need to be initialized after jpa. There are dependencies between them.**

1. ModelDynamismInformation
2. ModelEntityInformation
3. ModelInformation
4. ModelPrimaryKeyInformation
5. ModelSchemaInformation
6. ModelSecurityInformation
7. PolicyInitializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@DependsOn` to control the order in which beans get initialized. A bean depending on an EntityManagerFactory should get initialized after Hibernate did its schema creation.